# What's the probability that a shuffled standard deck of 52 cards has two top cards of the same rank?

Tags: probability

I have done many problems involving color and suit, but I am not sure how rank fits in..

For example: 13(13C2/52C2).

You calculate the probability for 1 rank and multiply it by 13?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thought process is indeed correct, however you made a mistake.  It wouldn't be $\frac{13\binom{\color{red}{13}}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$, it would be $\frac{13\binom{\color{red}{4}}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$.  Once we picked which of the thirteen ranks it was, we then pick which two of the *suits* it was, and there are four suits available.  Note however there is an easier way to think of it.

*Whatever* the first card happened to be, we ask what the probability is that the *second* card is the same rank as the first.  As there are $51$ cards left, $3$ of which have the same rank as the first card, the probability is simply $\frac{3}{51}$.  You can check that this gives the same answer as before.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The first card can be anything.  After that, how many cards are left?  How many of them have the same rank as the first card?

Following your approach, there are four cards of each rank and you need to select two of them.  One of the numbers in your expression is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of possible orderings is $52!$.

Now, to get an order we're interested in, we first choose one out of $13$ ranks in $\binom{13}1=13$ ways, then choose $2$ out of the $4$ cards of that rank in $\binom{4}2=6$ ways, and finally choose one of the $2!$ orders for these two. For each such choice, we may yet order the remaining $50$ cards in $50!$ ways. The probability is hence

$$\frac{13\cdot 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 50!}{52!}=\frac{13\cdot 12}{52\cdot 51}=\frac1{17}\simeq 5.88\%$$